# Phonegap 2.1.0 to Cordova 3.5.1 loadurl not working

Tags: android, cordova

A few weeks ago I got the email from Google advising me to upgrade me app to 3.5.1 or risk the app being taken down.

My app is android specific and I'm building it in Android Studio so I've included the updated .jar file and updated the .js and all that stuff.

Everything seems to be fine when navigating around my included html pages but I'm running into trouble when opening an external webpage.

```
public class MyActivity extends CordovaActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadUrl(getString(R.string.indexURL));
}

@Override
public void init() {
    final String os = "Android";
    final String version = getVersion();
    CordovaWebView webView = new CordovaWebView(this);

    init(webView, new CordovaWebViewClient(this, webView) {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            boolean redirected = false;
            //If the page you're accessing is the root or login page
            if (url.endsWith("/Login")) {
                //redirect to root page with query string
                appView.loadUrl((getString(R.string.mainURL) + "?os=" + os + "&version=" + version));
                redirected = true;
            }
            return redirected;
        }
    }, new CordovaChromeClient(this, webView));
}
```

As soon as I upgraded I commented out a few things to do with the Google analytics plugin I'm using and tested and my external urls didn't load.
MyActivity was extending from DroidGap so I updated it to extend from CordovaActivity instead but same issue is applying. I can see it hitting the Url redirecting code ut it doesn't do anything afterwards.

```
10-14 12:28:46.166  10958-10958/com.example.Example D/CordovaWebView﹕ >>> loadUrl(https://www.MyWebsite.com.au/Login/?os=Android&version=2.0.0)
10-14 12:28:46.166  10958-10958/com.example.Example D/PluginManager﹕ init()
10-14 12:28:46.166  10958-10958/com.example.Example D/CordovaWebView﹕ >>> loadUrlNow()
10-14 12:29:06.166  10958-10958/com.example.Example E/CordovaWebView﹕ CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
```

Does anything stand out as wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was a combination of the config.xml being in the wrong format with `<plugin>` tags rather than `<feature>` tags.

also changed

```
if (url.endsWith("/Login")) {
            //redirect to root page with query string
            appView.loadUrl((getString(R.string.mainURL) + "?os=" + os + "&version=" + version));
            redirected = true;
        }
```

to

```
if (url.endsWith("/Login")) {
            //redirect to root page with query string
            loadUrl((getString(R.string.mainURL) + "?os=" + os + "&version=" + version));
            redirected = true;
        }
```